# Trying to force stop Subtitle in Google drive embed videos

Tags: google-drive-api

Is that possible to force turn off subtitle of Google drive embed videos?

When I run the video it auto run the subtitle how can I do that from iframe ? what should I add to the source url ?

I've tried to add "&cc_load_policy=0" to the url
like this :

```
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/<?php echo $row_Movie['WO']; ?>/preview?autoplay=1&hl=es&cc_lang_pref=es&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0
```

but the subtitle is still shown when I open the video also I tried to add `yt:cc=off` to the url but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done :( its from iframe so you can't edit it